I think my static file is causing the problem
I am new to spring boot. I use a book to practice and I found this problem when I run the program. The error is "There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No static resource".
My pom
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>tmang.luvtocode</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

My PostController.java controller
package tmang.luvtocode.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import tmang.luvtocode.domain.Post;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/posts")
public class PostController {
    
    @GetMapping(value="") 
    public String postPage(Model model){
        Post post = new Post();
        post.setTitle("Hello Spring Boot");
        post.setDescription("Spring Boot");
        post.setBody("Spring Boot is Awesome");
        model.addAttribute("post", post);
        return "post";
    }
}

These are my data
My Post class
package tmang.luvtocode.domain;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Post {
      private Integer id;
      private String title;
      private String description;
      private String body;
      private String slug;
      private PostStatus postStatus;
      private LocalDateTime createdOn;
      private LocalDateTime updatedOn;
      private List<Comment> comments;
}

My Comment data class
package tmang.luvtocode.domain;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Comment {
   private Integer id;
   private String title;
   private String authorName;
   private String body;
   private LocalDateTime createdOn;
   private LocalDateTime updatedOn;
}

My PostStatus enum
package tmang.luvtocode.domain;

public enum PostStatus {
   DRAFT,PUBLISHED
}

My DemoApplication class
package tmang.luvtocode.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}

My post.html which is situated in the template
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Spring Blog</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Welcome to Spring Blog</h1>

    <h3 th:text="${post.title}"></h3>
    <h6 th:text="${post.description}"></h6>
    <div th:text="{post.body}"></div>
</body>

</html>

Can anyone help me solve this problem
